# In-game Dash not consistent, I think effected by velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 3D fps, and want a dash. The player uses a character controller, and no rigidbody. My original implementation:

```
    x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); //just gets ur wasd inputs by default
    z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z; //creates a movement vector
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);  //moves the player


    if (currentDashLength < dashLength ) //dashes for a set time period
            {
                currentDashLength += Time.deltaTime;
                velocity.y = 0; //keeps you up in the air
                controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * dashSpeed);
            }
            else
            {
                currentDashLength = dashLength;
                isDashing = false;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dashTimer >= 1 && !isCrouching)
            {
                isDashing = true;
                dashTimer -= 1;
                currentDashLength = 0f;
                health.GiveIFrames(dashLength); 
            }
```

This dash works fine, but I realized that if you had pressed shift right after starting to move, the dash would be significantly weaker. I assumed this was due to the fact that my current velocity was low, so the acceleration from the Move function didn't make me reach the speed I would when already moving at terminal velocity. I tried to fix this by multiplying the Move function inputs by 1/(the horizontal velocity of the player) but this didn't fix the issue. My full dashing code:

```
    float dispX = transform.position.x - posX; //gets chnage in position since last frame, this is important to caluclate velocity, since the player isnt using a rigidbody
    float dispY = transform.position.y - posY;
    float dispZ = transform.position.z - posZ;
    
    posX = transform.position.x;
    posY = transform.position.y;
    posZ = transform.position.z;
    
    float horizontalVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(dispX*dispX + dispZ*dispZ) / Time.deltaTime;

    x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); //just gets ur wasd inputs by default
    z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z; //creates a movement vector
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);  //moves the player
    
    if (currentDashLength < dashLength )
            {
                currentDashLength += Time.deltaTime;
                velocity.y = 0;
                if(horizontalVelocity == 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Cannot dash while standing still");
                }
                else
                {
                    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * dashSpeed * (1 / horizontalVelocity));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentDashLength = dashLength;
                isDashing = false;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dashTimer >= 1 && !isCrouching)
            {
                isDashing = true;
                dashTimer -= 1;
                currentDashLength = 0f;
                health.GiveIFrames(dashLength); 
            }
```

How would I go about ensuring that the dash speed is constant?
(I tried to post this on unity answers, but the website isn't responding to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired behaviour I have re-written your original script by quite a lot, hope that is okay! This code only give you movement and dash control, and nothing else. You'll have to add your crouch check and health stuff back in.

Essentially, we check if the player is dashing before applying any movement, this way we don't add the dash to the current movement. If the player is dashing, we ignore their forward input and apply forward movement based on the predetermined dash. If we aren't dashing then we apply the calculated movement as usual.

```
private CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float dashSpeed = 20.0f;
    public float dashLength = 0.5f;
    private float currentDashLength = 0;
    private bool isDashing = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        // Same as before

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        // gets the move direction

        // before we move, check if dashing
        if (isDashing)
        {
            currentDashLength += Time.deltaTime;
            move = new Vector3(move.x * dashSpeed, move.y, 1 * dashSpeed);
            // this gets the current player movement, and replaces the forward velocity rather than adding to it. We add to the sideways velocity to allow for slight directional control.
            // do this instead if you want the dash to only move the player in the forward direction, and prevent strafing: move = new Vector3(move.x, move.y, 1 * dashSpeed);

            if (currentDashLength >= dashLength) // when we run out of time, set dash to false
            {
                isDashing = false;
            }
        }

        else // if we are not dashing then move as normal
        {
            move *= speed;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && move.magnitude > 0) // stops the dash ability being used when stationary
            {
                isDashing = true;
                currentDashLength = 0;
            }
        }

        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: I managed to figure out this problem myself using the most incomprehensible and abhorrent programming ever seen, but it works how I wanted it to. But reading through this code, I see what my issue was before. Thanks anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

```
float dispX = transform.position.x - posX;
float dispY = transform.position.y - posY;
float dispZ = transform.position.z - posZ;
    
posX = transform.position.x;
posY = transform.position.y;
posZ = transform.position.z;
    
float horizontalVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(dispX*dispX + dispZ*dispZ) / Time.deltaTime;

x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    
if (currentDashLength < dashLength )
{
    currentDashLength += Time.deltaTime;
    velocity.y = 0;

    Vector3 dashMove = move * Time.deltaTime * dashSpeed; // Calculates the dash movement vector

    // Move the player based on the dash movement vector
    controller.Move(dashMove);
}
else
{
    currentDashLength = dashLength;
    isDashing = false;
}

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dashTimer >= 1 && !isCrouching)
{
    isDashing = true;
    dashTimer -= 1;
    currentDashLength = 0f;
    health.GiveIFrames(dashLength); 
}
```

By calculating the dash movement vector independently from the player's horizontal velocity, you can ensure that the dash speed remains constant regardless of whether the player is moving before dashing or not.

I think this is what you were trying to achieve? Hope it helps!

Comment: This is what I originally did if you look at the 1st code block, but this didn't work. Lets say I had just pressed w, and started moving forward. It takes me about 0.2s to reach terminal velocity, which was about 20. If I dashed at this speed it was consistent, but if dashed right after pressing w, before reaching terminal velocity, it would not work correctly. I think this is because the move function accelerates me, so for example if I'm at v=20, I would reach v=40 while dashing, but if I pressed it in that small time frame, I wouldn't reach the desired speed, but less.